# How to specify an offset with add-symbol-file command which get added to all sections in gdb

Tags: gdb

I have one shared object file which gets loaded in memory dynamically using add-symbol-file in gdb.

gdb) add-symbol-file shared.so 0x1234

Doing this .text section loaded at 0x1234 memory. We can specify a section-specific address also.
Can we specify of offset which can get added to all section addresses?

Similar like --slide in lldb debugger. which slides LOAD address by offset.

Comment: Isn't the what the `-o offset` parameter of [add-symbol-file](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#index-add_002dsymbol_002dfile) is for?

Comment: That supposed to be applied on all sections of image but actually it not work like this.

Answer (score 0):

> I have one shared object file which gets loaded in memory dynamically

On most platforms, whey you dynamically load a shared object (e.g. via `dlopen`), GDB will *automatically* add symbols from it *without* the need to `add-symbol-file`.

If that *isn't* happening, you should describe your platform, and the mechanism by which the shared object gets loaded.

> Can we specify of offset which can get added to all section addresses?

Yes.

Assuming the shared object was added with relocation `0x123456000`, and that the `.text` section in that shared object starts at offset `0xabcd`, `add-symbol-file 0x123456000+0xabcd` will do *exactly* what you want.